# Laravel Vue spa get current auth user details

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js, laravel-sanctum

I'm using Vue and Laravel Sanctum to handle login. This is my html form

```
<form action="#" @submit.prevent="handleLogin">
    <input type="text" v-model="form.email">Name<br/>
    <input type="text" v-model="form.password">Password<br/>
    <button>Submit</button><br/>
</form>
```

and this is the method used to handle login

```
  handleLogin () {


            axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {

               axios.post('/login', this.form).then(response => {
                    this.logged_in = true

               })

            });

        }
```

So, this does handle the login but I cannot get the details of the authenticated user unless I refresh the page, which I don't want to do.

To try to circumvent this problem, I'm passing the details of the authenticated user from my controller to my view

```
$auth_user = Auth::user();

return view('maintenance.contractor_maintenances', compact('auth_user'));
```

And then in my view I pass it as a prop to my Vue component

```
<app-contractors-maintenance :auth_user="{{ json_encode($auth_user) }}"/>
```

and in my component

```
 props: {
        auth_user: {
            required: true,
        }
    }
```

but when I `{{ auth_user }}` in my component it also works only when the page is refreshed, and I want as soon as I login with Sanctum, those auth details are updated. Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should probably have the `/login` route return the logged in user details so you can update that info in vue app

Comment: alternatively, make a third call to an api route that would allow you to get the users info